# How to prevent corners on CSS box-shadow?

Tags: css

I'm trying to add a bottom `box-shadow` to a header bar with 100% width of the screen. However I'm ending up with rounded corners as pictured:

[image]

**How can I extend the shadow so it doesn't have visible corners on either side?**

[JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/K88H9/4512/)

Comment: something like this http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/K88H9/4513/ ? You obviously applied an offset of `-2px` for the `spread`, so it does not expand normally. You can also try an offset of `1px` for a clearer line.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/K88H9/4514/

Comment: @Moob why don't you add that as an answer to this question so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the [`box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) a *horizontal offset* of zero, a *vertical offset* of zero, a *blur radius* of 4px to soften it and a *spread radius* of 4px to increase its size. Finally give it a *colo[u]r*. The shadow itself is actually around the element equally - we just can't see it where it overflows the page.

```
#shadow {
    top:0;
    background-color: #3D668F;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 4px 4px #232323;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0px 4px 4px #232323;
    box-shadow: 0 0px 4px 4px #232323;    
}
```

[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K88H9/4514/)